# I can't use the UBound() function in VBA Access. Seems like it's not recognised

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I work on access 2013 and I have a problem using UBound(). The compiler doesn't recognise the function. Maybe there is a specific library this function is from, but it wasn't mentionned on microsoft website.
Here is the code I used :

```
Dim Key(2)  As String

Key(0) = "0"
Key(1) = "1"
Key(2) = "2"

UBound(Key,1)
```

Does anyone has the same issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your code compile properly if you do something with the value returned by `UBound`, perhaps like this?  `MsgBox UBound(Key, 1)`

Comment: Yes it works like that thanks :) HansUp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a function that you need to assign it's return to something.

```
Dim i As Integer
i = UBound(Key, 1)
```

You can also use it's return as a variable

```
For i = 1 to UBound(Key, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you MatthewD, as soon as I put the "=" in front of the Ubound the compiler eventually recognised it.